# How can I search within a table of comma-separated values?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a MySQL table which contains comma-separated values like this:

```
first row=(3,56,78,12)  
second row=(6,44,2,3)  
third row=(67,4,2,7,1)  
fourth row=(88,55,22,33)  
fifth row=(88,55,3,1,5)
```

I want to select the rows which have `3` in their set. How can I do this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987829/searching-from-comma-separated-value and of a number of others in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+search+in+comma+separated+values

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL search in comma list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458703/mysql-search-in-comma-list)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Field LIKE '3,%'
OR Field LIKE '%,3'
OR Field LIKE '%,3,%'
OR Field = '3'
```

Comment: I thought it would match 13,23,33, etc too but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 3, COLUMN_NAME )
```

Comment: This only returns result if comma separated string starts from 3

Answer (score 3):

Just Use Mysql Function `FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)` .

Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic. Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string. Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', column_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this condition

```
WHERE firstrow LIKE '3,%' 
    OR firstrow like '%,3'
    OR firstrow like '3'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Field IN ($first_row)
OR Field IN ($second_row)
OR Field IN ($third_row)
OR Field IN ($fourth_row);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IN` statement in your query.Please try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Field IN ($first_row)
OR Field IN ($second_row)
OR Field IN ($third_row)
OR Field IN ($fourth_row);
```