# MySQL search in comma list

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL field with a reference to another table where ids are saved as comma seperated list, eg:

```
12,13,14,16
```

which stand for values in another table. I know this is very bad and wrong, but this comes from above and I cant do anything about that. The problem now is that i want to search in that field with a query like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE field LIKE '%1%'
```

The Problem now is obviously that almost all entries can be found with this example Query, because the most common IDs are in Range 10-20. My Idea is to search for %,1,% instead, but this does not work for the first and last id in the field. Ist there something like an internal replace or how do i fix this the best way?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', field)
```

Comment: how to find multiple values

Comment: Beware: `FIND_IN_SET` doesn't uses indexes on table.

Answer (score 18):

Be aware that plain `FIND_IN_SET` is case-insensitive,

i.e. `FIND_IN_SET('b3','a1,a2,B3,b3')` and `FIND_IN_SET('B3','a1,a2,B3,b3')` both return 3.

To be case sensitive, add 'binary' modifier to the 1st argument, e.g. `FIND_IN_SET (binary 'b3', 'a1,a2,B3,b3')` returns 4.

Answer (score 7):

As others have said, Find_In_Set will let you write the query, but you really need to look at your database design (and I know you know this...)

The trouble with including Foreign Keys in a delimited list like this is that whole point of a foreign key is to enable you to locate the information in the other table quickly, using Indexes. By implementing a database as it sounds you have, you have all sorts of issues to resolve:

- How do I prevent duplicates (which would waste space)
- How do I remove a given value (Requires custom function, leading to possibility of errors?
- How do I respond to performance issues as the size of my tables increase?

There's only one truly acceptable way to address this - which is not to face the problem in the first place.

Have a sit down chat with those on high, and explain the problems with their solution - then explain the advantages of doing the job properly.

If they won't even discuss the point, look for a job with a decent employer who values your contributions.

Martin.

Answer (score 4):

[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) is your best bet

```
 SELECT ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1,field_name)
```

Comment: The first parameter needs to be a string.

Answer (score 3):

After reading this question Id like to add that if your comma delimited list has spaces i.e. (1, 2,3 ,4) you will need to remove the leading/trailing spaces or use WHERE FIND_IN_SET(X,field) OR FIND_IN_SET(' X',field) OR FIND_IN_SET('X ',field)..... Just thought i'd share that since i came across that problem..... just gotta create those databases right the first time or they will give you all kinds of trouble.