# RLIKE with subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a query

```
select X from survey
where survey_date > date_add(curdate(), interval -90 day)
```

which shows which X are current.  But unfortunately through circumstances outside my control, the returned values are not a list of values but a list of lists of comma-separated values.  So it returns

```
| X                  |
+--------------------+
|thing1              |
|thing2,thing3,thing4|
|thing5              |
|thing6,thing7       |
```

and so forth.

Now I wanted to use this as a subquery.  If the data was one to a line, I would do

```
select Y from othertable
where irrelevant_conditions && Y not in (
    select X from survey
    where survey_date > date_add(curdate(), interval -90 day)
);
```

But this does not work since I might have, say `thing3`.

Instead I need to do `RLIKE`. (As it happens the data cannot collide by their form, so no extra regexp magic is needed here to check for commas.) Is that possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search into a comma separated string you can use [find_in_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458703/mysql-search-in-comma-list). If Y is not an string a implicid cast operation is maded.

```
select Y from othertable 
where irrelevant_conditions && not exists (
    select  1
    from survey
    where 
     survey_date > date_add(curdate(), interval -90 day) and
     find_in_set(othertable.Y, X) > 0 
);
```

Comment: That looks like just the right thing.  But when I run the subquery with some specific value for Y it gives me nothing when it should give me something.

Comment: the parameters are reversed! try `select find_in_set('bar', f) ...`

Answer (score 0):

danhip's convoluted query can be simplified to:

```
select Y from othertable 
join survey on survey_date > date_add(curdate(), interval -90 day)
    and find_in_set(othertable.Y, X) = 0 
where irrelevant_conditions
```

Comment: This pulls up cases where there is some row for which `find_in_set(othertable.Y, X) = 0`, rather than for which it is 0 for all rows.