# Count the number of followers and print it PHP

Tags: php

I have this in my BD:

following: 12,13,2,4 (this is the user id of the following list of one user)

and I want to count how many followers has a single user.

I have this code:

```
  $followers = $db->fetch_field($db->simple_select('users', 'COUNT(*) AS followers' , "buddylist IN ($useruid) "), 'followers');
  $Followers = $followers;
```

This only works if the first number of the list is the same that $useruid.
Example:

$useruid = 1,
buddylist = 3,2,1

```
$followers = $db->fetch_field($db->simple_select('users', 'COUNT(*) AS followers' , "buddylist IN ($useruid) "), 'followers');
      $Followers = $followers;
```

the out put its 0

if buddylist is 1,2,3

the output is one.

What's wrong? :(

Comment: Do you want a PHP solution? Return the string, explode by comma and count bits, otherwise a SQL solution would need to do something similar

Comment: sql or php whatever :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead of `IN()`, since `IN` will look for the string you compare in a group of structured fields, whereas your field is a comma separated string of IDs. [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458703/mysql-search-in-comma-list) will look within that string:

```
$followers = $db->fetch_field(
    $db->simple_select(
        'users',
        'COUNT(*) AS followers',
        "FIND_IN_SET($useruid, buddylist)"
    ),
    'followers'
);
```

[See this related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in)

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to tell not knowing your DB contents.

I suppose you have users in $useruid as array

convert your array to string by `implode(',',$useruid)` and substitute $useruid before mysql statment

and all should work fine