# Matching multiple values against existing strings in one field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For example, when a table has a record column named 'product' that contain value such as: 'Laptop, Desktop, Case'. How can I validate these 3 values that break down with a comma against two PHP variables value with `$var1='Laptop'` and `$var2='Desktop'` ? So that this row can be found! However, the two variables could be passed in the order of 'Desktop', 'Laptop' as well. Meanwhile, the column could have pattern of 'Case, Desktop, Laptop'. I wonder if there is a solution in MySQL for this kind of scenario that somehow, pick up each element like PHP could and match them with each var individually.

Comment: i don't think this is possible in mysql, but if you wanted to use PHP, you could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for this...

Comment: the 'find_in_set' function may be useful: [436591/how-can-i-search-within-a-table-of-comma-separated-values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436591/how-can-i-search-within-a-table-of-comma-separated-values).

Comment: Do not wonder any longer. Everything comparison related Mysql has to offer is also documented in the mysql manual. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your table structure this is a quick example of what you can do.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE $var1 IN (SELECT product FROM table WHERE something = somethingelse) AND  $var2 IN (SELECT product FROM table WHERE something = somethingelse)
```

Comment: how will this get the OP the values separated by a comma into separate variables?

Comment: the product field is already in csv format from what the op said. So when it returns csv the original query checks if var1 is in that csv. Then it checks if var2 is in that csv

Comment: this makes no sense: if you check 'Laptop' against 'Laptop, Desktop, Case' with equality, how will that every be true?

Comment: Its not checking equality. IN is not the same as =

Comment: I use this method all the time. It works fine.

Comment: ...but `something = somethingelse` does... and so your query will never work... you're probably using it without looking inside a specific value, not among many values, not the same

Comment: that is obviously because he only wants one row to get the product list from. Like I said I dont know his table structure. I dont know his field names. I used those as an example. It would be replaced with something to get that certain row. That certain row has the field with the csv.

Comment: @Brian For this piece `$var1 IN (SELECT product FROM table WHERE something = somethingelse)` if there is a IN matched, that means this phrase will equivalent of a TRUE, is that correct?

Comment: yes. If var1 is Laptop and the subquery returns Laptop, Desktop, Case it will be true

Comment: @Brian does SQL can ever break down comma seperated text to validate each seperate string part with a select you wrote?

Comment: so what is `something` or `somethingelse` in this query going out from the example provided by the OP?

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean. Are you asking if you can use a comma seperated value as the variable to check against the csv from the product field?

Comment: @webeno THe something and somethingelse are column names and what after it could be the variables I think :)

Comment: sorry, this makes no sense at all to me...

Comment: Yes see Chen understands. Obviously theres more than one row. There has to be some way to determine which row you are reading the products field from.

Comment: @Brian Its ok, I think this solution is good enough atm :) THanks!

Comment: This answer simply doesn't answer the question, either one of them is wrong, sorry. @boulder_02's answer is the one that actually answers this properly, to my view.

Comment: @Brian Comes out, seem boulder_02 will also work. I am pretty undecided in this case. I will get back to you all once I impliment into a actual test run! THanks

Comment: lol webeno just because you dont understand something doesnt mean it doesnt work. This method works perfectly fine. If another method works too, great. But don't try to make someone else as ignorant as you just because you dont understand it.

Comment: And the LIKE method will only work if none of the words are similar. If you have Desktop and Desktop1 and DesktopComputer, all of them will match to %Desktop%

Comment: @Brian That is really a good point hum... really interesting!

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want the data to be found, if the column 'product' contains 'Laptop' or 'Desktop'. Write this with the LIKE operator in your query:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE `product` LIKE '%Desktop%' OR `product` LIKE '%Laptop%'"
```

If you pass the variables it would be:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE `product` LIKE '%$var1%' OR `product` LIKE '%$var2%'"
```

Make sure to use the % sign before and after the searched string, so that it will match even if the keyword is anwhere inside the product content.

Comment: But this also involve possibility of that var 1 could be laptop and var2 could be desktop, which is the reverse, while this query will not able to match... Await your revised answer :)

Comment: It will match. You defined an OR switch. If condition 1 is false, it will go on with condirion 2. One of them will be true, so the product will be selected

Comment: I just read, that you want match, if both variables are in the product description. In that case you have to change OR against AND. It's irrelevant, which keyword is fed into the query as first.

Comment: Hum... interesting. Both you guys solution seem could work. I will actually implimented and then back for the mark on answer! Thanks :)

Comment: This will not work if you are trying to match a word that is contained in multiple words. If you are checking for Desktop and yhe list includes Desktop, Desktop1, Dektop2, etc they will all match %Desktop%