# Yii2 Active Record using FIND_IN_SET in where clause

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, yii, yii2

**Product** Table Structure and data -

> id, product_name, hsn, product_category, product_subcategory, company,
>   pic, part_no, min_stock, stock, rate, notes

The product_subcategory column contains the values like for eg.

```
13,14,31,138
18
126,140,176,177
78,79
```

The above numbers are ids of the following table

**`product_subcategory`** -
id, subcategory_name

While creating an Invoice I need to search the product by the combination of `product_category, product_subcategory, company`.

For this, I have the ajax as follows

```
<?php
$script2 = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document.body).on('change', '#purchaseitems-0-category_id, #purchaseitems-0-model_id, #purchaseitems-0-company_id', function () {

    var tt = $("#purchaseitems-0-category_id").val();
    var tt2 = $("#purchaseitems-0-model_id").val();
    var tt3 = $("#purchaseitems-0-company_id").val();

    var stuff1 ={'key1': tt ,'key2': tt2, 'key3': tt3};     
    p1();
});
});

function p1() {
        var stuff ={'key1':$("#purchaseitems-0-category_id").val(),'key2':$("#purchaseitems-0-model_id").val(), 'key3': $("#purchaseitems-0-company_id").val()};

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/yii-application/backend/web/index.php?r=purchase/p1",
            data: {result:JSON.stringify(stuff)},
            success: function (test4) {

            var json_obj5 = $.parseJSON(test4);

            $('#purchaseitems-0-name_of_product').val(json_obj5.id);
            $('#purchaseitems-0-hsn').val(json_obj5.hsn);
            $('#purchase-taxrate').val(json_obj5.rate);
            $('#purchaseitems-0-part').val(json_obj5.part_no);
                    },
                    error: function (exception) {
                        alert(exception);
                    }                   

                });
    }
 JS;
  $this->registerJs($script2);
 ?>
```

Now the real code which needs to be changed -

```
public function actionP1()
    {
        $data2 = Yii::$app->request->post('result');
        $data    = $_POST["result"];
        $data    = json_decode("$data", true);
        if (isset($data)) {
            $test = $data;
            $modelfedbkshiprate = \backend\models\Product::find()->where(['product_category' => $data["key1"]])->andWhere(['like' , 'product_subcategory' , $data["key2"]])->andWhere(['company' => $data["key3"]])->one();
        } else {
            $test = "Ajax failed";
        }
        return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($modelfedbkshiprate);          
    }
```

The issue with the above query is the **`like`** operator in `product_subcategory`.
The `like` operator searches the `id 7` instead of `78` and therefore I end up getting a wrong product. I thought of using `FIND_IN_SET` but don't know how.

Please suggest an alternate solution to `like` operator.

Comment: your question is not clear how come you are using `like` operator for `key3` and not for the rest of them, which is coming from the field `purchaseitems-0-model_id` and is unknown as no `HTML` added, is it a multi-select drop-down that is selecting multiple `id`'s ?

Comment: I am using like operator for key2 not key3. The reason i am using it is the product_subcategory column in product table has values - 13,14,31,138
18
126,140,176,177
78,79        but the remaining columns product_category, company has single value.

Comment: I was trying to work with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436591/how-can-i-search-within-a-table-of-comma-separated-values

Comment: so you have comma-separated list of values inside the `product_subcategory` and you want to list the results if the given `product_subcategory` exists? is it what you are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**`FIND_IN_SET`**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set/) to achieve this, as I understood you have the comma-separated values in the `product_subcategory` field and you want to get the row which has that specific id that is passed via the form to your `SQL` query.

So you need to use the `\yii\db\Expression` inside the `where` clause like below.

```
\backend\models\Product::find()
->where(['product_category' => $data["key1"]])
->andWhere(new \yii\db\Expression('FIND_IN_SET(:cat_to_find,product_subcategory)'))
->andWhere(['company' => $data["key3"]])
->addParams([':cat_to_find' => $data["key2"]])
->one();
```

Your action should look like this

```
public function actionP1()
    {
        $data2 = Yii::$app->request->post('result');
        $data    = $_POST["result"];
        $data    = json_decode("$data", true);
        if (isset($data)) {
            $test = $data;
            $modelfedbkshiprate = \backend\models\Product::find()->where(['product_category' => $data["key1"]])->andWhere(new \yii\db\Expression('FIND_IN_SET(:cat_to_find,product_subcategory)'))->andWhere(['company' => $data["key3"]])->addParams([':cat_to_find' => $data["key2"]])->one();
        } else {
            $test = "Ajax failed";
        }
        return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($modelfedbkshiprate);          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this (Find_In_SET ) is working for me.

```
Categories::find()->where(new Expression('FIND_IN_SET(:category_to_find, categories)'))->addParams([':category_to_find' => 3])->asArray()->all();
```

Comment: you should post an answer only if the technique or approach you are using for the answer isn't mentioned in any of the other answers, which isn't the case here.