# MySQL & PHP : Multiple Keyword Search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string containing comma separated keywords. For Example:

```
$keywords = 'keyword1, keyword2, keyword3';
```

My Table schema, named `tbl_address` is like this ( simplified ) :

```
id        INT(11)        PRIMARY KEY, AUTO INCREMENT
address   VARCHAR(250)   NOT NULL
```

Assume I have to use `MySQLi` in PHP ( not `PDO` ).

Here is my current approach:

```
$result = array();
$keyword_tokens = explode(',', $keywords);
foreach($keyword_tokens as $keyword) {
  $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($keyword));
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_address WHERE address LIKE'%$keyword%'";
  // query and collect the result to $result
  // before inserting to $result, check if the id exists in $result.
  // if yes, skip.
}
return $result;
```

This approach works, but inefficient in performance. If there are a lot of keywords, it will make a lot queries.

My question is, is there a better way to achieve the same goal ? i.e. what is the simplest way to return all records with the address containing the ANY of the keywords ?

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736386/1983854

Comment: Combining “LIKE” and “IN”: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server

Comment: @Shivian Seriously, why didn't you use my REGEXP one-liner?

Comment: If the keyword contains regular expression keywords, the query will fail, or generate unexpected result, e.g. keyword = `'|=|=|'`

Comment: @Raptor Looking at the upvotes, and that you know how to write a regex, perhaps you should edit the most upvoted answer to contain a decent regex and then mark that as correct. The current 'marked' answer isn't used much by other users :-)

Comment: Sadly I have no permission to change accepted answer.

Comment: Of course you do, this is your question ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A simple `REGEXP` might be what you're after. You'd have to check how efficient it is for yourself.

`SELECT * FROM tbl_address WHERE field REGEXP 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3';`

Comment: +1, this was exactly what I was looking for, I also learned a new `MySQL` string function!

Comment: Excellent answer, this has helped me resolve a weeks worth of research and helped me jump over 30% of my issue :)

Answer (score 5):

```
 SELECT * FROM user;
 +---------+----------+
 | user_id | username |
 +---------+----------+
 |     101 | Adam     |
 |     102 | Ben      |
 |     103 | Charlie  |
 |     104 | Dave     |
 +---------+----------+

 SELECT * 
   FROM user 
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(username,'adam,ben,dave') > 0;
 +---------+----------+
 | user_id | username |
 +---------+----------+
 |     101 | Adam     |
 |     102 | Ben      |
 |     104 | Dave     |
 +---------+----------+
```

Comment: Just a pair of caveats with this approach. Can't use the LIKE syntax and doesn't trim the keywords...

Answer (score 3):

You only need an 'OR', nothing else...

```
<?php

$result = array();
$keyword_tokens = explode(',', $keywords);
$keyword_tokens = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $keyword_tokens);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_address WHERE address LIKE'%";
$sql .= implode("%' or address LIKE '%", $keyword_tokens) . "'";

// query and collect the result to $result
// before inserting to $result, check if the id exists in $result.
// if yes, skip.

return $result;
```

**edit: Just to be sure you also trim the keywords**

```
<?php

$result = array();
$keyword_tokens = explode(',', $keywords);
$keyword_tokens = array_map(
    function($keyword) {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($keyword));
    }, 
    $keyword_tokens
);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_address WHERE address LIKE'%";
$sql .= implode("%' OR address LIKE '%", $keyword_tokens) . "'";

// query and collect the result to $result
// before inserting to $result, check if the id exists in $result.
// if yes, skip.

return $result;
```

Also, you should also pass the db resource link to the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function...

Comment: you missed a trailing single quote for the `$sql` though.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use fulltext search.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

if you don't want to use fulltext you can use OR in your WHERE condition

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_address WHERE address LIKE '%$keyword%' OR adress LIKE '%$keyword2%'
```

Comment: If you have multiple keywords you can make a string like ::->
SELECT * FROM tbl_address WHERE address LIKE "%key1%key2%key3%"

Answer (score 1):

Make single query

```
$keywordary = explode(',', $keywords);
foreach($keywordary as $keyword) {
  $keys = trim($keyword);
    $other .=" or address like '%$keys%'";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_address WHERE address LIKE'%$keyword%' $other";

execute query;
return $result;
```

Comment: Should this not be `$other .="` instead of `$other ="` inside your loop? Otherwise, you're cancelling out the `or` clause in each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try WHERE IN clause:

```
$keyword = (array)explode(',', $keywords);
for($i=0;$i=count($keyword);$i++){
   $keyword[$i]=mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($keyword[$i]),'\'" ');
}
//This is what I suggest.
$query='SELECT * FROM tbl_address WHERE address IN ("'.implode('","',$keyword).'")';
```

Successfully tested on MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is just create search string WHERE clause and append it to query and run it once.

```
$result = array();
$keyword_tokens = explode(',', $keywords);
$where = '';$i=0
foreach($keyword_tokens as $keyword) {
  $where.= " address LIKE'%".mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($keyword))."%' OR ";
}
  // trim last OR with substr_replace
  substr_replace($where, "OR", -1, 1);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_address WHERE $where";

return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi create a query with union and execute in the end of the loop

```
$result = array();
$keyword_tokens = explode(',', $keywords);
$sql = '';
foreach($keyword_tokens as $keyword) {
  $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($keyword));
  if (!empty($sql)) $sql .= " UNION "; 
  $sql .= "SELECT * FROM tbl_address WHERE address LIKE'%$keyword%'";
  // query and collect the result to $result
  // before inserting to $result, check if the id exists in $result.
  // if yes, skip.
}
```

Execute the  query here.