# PHP : Passing DB Link Identifier into array_map's inner function

Tags: php

Based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16034581/188331)'s answer , I have to use an inner function for `array_map()` as follow:

```
    $keyword_tokens = array_map(
        function($keyword) {
            return $this->db->escape_string(trim($keyword));
        }, $keyword_tokens
    );
```

`$this->db` is a MySQLi database wrapper, while its function `escape_string()` is a wrapper of `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

The problem is, PHP prompts error:

> **Fatal error:** Using $this when not in object context

However, the `array_map` code piece is within a public function within a class. My question is: How can I reference `$this->db` in the `array_map()`'s inner function ?

Comment: Why aren't you using prepared statements?

Comment: Please read my previous question, prepared statements did not apply to that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `use` keyword to include variables in the closure's scope, though you'll have to use a different variable to `$this` if you're using a PHP version prior to 5.4. Perhaps this...

```
$db = $this->db;
$keyword_tokens = array_map(
    function($keyword) use ($db) {
        return $db->escape_string(trim($keyword));
    }, $keyword_tokens
);
```