# Get products by multiple category id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to do this kind of query,
When i make the query by get, i want to display the results from the id, for example if i have this id in my GET =11;

I want to display all the products with the category_id = 11, even if they have another id in the concat format, I don't know how i can do this kind of query,

```
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `product_category_id`='$id'";
```

My product_category_id  contains the id's of the categories in CONCAT format:

```
product_category_id (type text)
11,30,29
```

Comment: Try this: `WHERE product_category_id IN($id)`

Comment: After read back, I don't understand because an identifier should be unique. If my first read was good it's a possible duplicate of [mysql where in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736284/mysql-where-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) MySQL function might be what you're looking for.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$id', `product_category_id`)";
```

Comment: As Aioros said though, it is worth remembering that this could result in a slow query.

Answer (score 0):

With a field like that, you will have to do something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM product
        WHERE product_category_id LIKE '$id,%'
        OR product_category_id LIKE '%,$id,%'
        OR product_category_id LIKE '%,$id'";
```

In general, though, this will be a slow query.