# Is it possible to edit a value of a column in multiple rows, by passing a vector?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to simplify this expression?

```
UPDATE `app01`.`ost_user` SET `org_id` = '2' WHERE `ost_user`.`id` = 6;
UPDATE `app01`.`ost_user` SET `org_id` = '2' WHERE `ost_user`.`id` = 7;
UPDATE `app01`.`ost_user` SET `org_id` = '2' WHERE `ost_user`.`id` = 8;
```

I was thinking in something like:

```
UPDATE `app01`.`ost_user` SET `org_id` = '2' WHERE `ost_user`.`id` = [6, 7, 8];
```

Is there any way?

I've already tried to find an answer to this question, but I dont even know which terms should I search...

Comment: Seems like you want the `in` operator - `UPDATE \`app01\`.\`ost_user\` SET \`org_id\` = '2'' WHERE \`ost_user\`.\`id\` in (6,7,8);`  - Be aware there can be pitfalls there multiple IDs - see [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736284/mysql-where-in) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try  with

```
UPDATE `app01`.`ost_user` SET `org_id` = '2' WHERE `ost_user`.`id` in (6, 7, 8);
```