# Dynamic SQL Command

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to be able to get only values where there is a '1' in multiple columns.
My column names are stored dynamically in a variable though.
How would I go about this?

This is what I have.
Columns are layed out like this
`$Columns = "Computer, Science, Algebra, Biology, Networking";`
 `//This is Dynamic so $Columns may be like this next time`
 `$Columns = "Biology, Networking";`
`$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE '1' IN(".$Columns.")";`

Right now, it selects any users that have a "1" in any of the columns

I only want to retrieve the users that have a "1" in `ALL` of the variables in the array `$Columns` not just one of them

Comment: I cant compare it like that, my column names come from one variable. Dynamically generated based on a drop down. So all columns are in one variable called $columns

Comment: It *can* be compared "like that". Generate the SQL appropriately. Start by creating an *array* of Column Names. Then appropriately join/iterate the array to build the SQL.

Comment: maybe using explode() i dont know. I've tried that with no success as well.

Comment: I already have an array of columns

Comment: I wrote $Columns = "blah, blah blah"; up top for an example. My $columns is in an array though.

Comment: You have a column for every subject in the users table? That's no good design. Consider using a linking table.

Comment: (Correction: I used 'OR', it should have been 'AND'.. for "all values")

Comment: Still makes 0 sense, you using OR or you using AND.

Comment: I understand OR and AND statements... I cannot use them with this variable.

Comment: If you know how, can you please stop playing mind games?

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736284/mysql-where-in) question on how `IN` works. It will return true if it found a match. If you want the query to succeed only when all the columns contain your value then you need to use `AND`

Comment: @hungrykoala How do I use and with my above variable, since all the column names are inside one variable?

Comment: Well, you could start off by exploding your variable so that you can separate your columns and do a loop to generate a new string like  Biology = '1' AND Networking = '1'

Answer (score 0):

Since your $columns variable can be different sizes, you will need to build your sql statement based on the number of columns in the array in a for loop:

```
// SET your first column IN
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE '1' IN (".$Columns(0).")"

//Run the for loop to build sql on all subsequent columns
// size of will give you the number of columns in your array
$max = sizeof($columns);
for($i = 1; $i < $max;$i++)
{
//Use the "AND" to make sure "1" is in all columns
$sql.=" AND '1' IN (".$Columns($i).")
}

$sql.=";"
```

My code may not be perfect, but should get you in the right direction.