# Searching products in multiple categories

Tags: php, mysql

I have this search function with categories and when you click on this category you will search within that category, however I want to make it so that I'm able to search a keyword within multiple categories. This is my form:

```
        <form method="get" action="zoek.php">
            <input type="text" name="producttitle" placeholder="Productnaam">
            <input type="hidden" name="prodgroup" value="<?= (isset($_GET['prodgroup'])) ? $_GET['prodgroup'] : '' ?>">
            <input type=submit class="btn btn-primary" value="Zoek...">
        </form>
```

This is the code where you clicked on a category and searched a word

```
      <?php
    if (isset($_GET['prodgroup']) && $_GET['prodgroup'] != "" && isset($_GET['producttitle']) && $_GET['producttitle'] != "") {
        $category = $_GET['prodgroup'];
        $prodtit = $_GET['producttitle'];


        $query = $readconn->prepare("
SELECT S.StockItemID, S.StockItemName, S.Photo, S.UnitPrice, S.Photo, S.Brand
FROM stockitems S JOIN stockitemstockgroups SISG ON S.StockItemID = SISG.StockItemID
JOIN stockgroups SG ON SISG.StockGroupID = SG.StockGroupID
WHERE SG.StockGroupID = '" . $category . "'
AND S.StockItemName LIKE '%" . $prodtit . "%'
");
```

These are the categories with their ID's:

`.--------------.---------------------.
| StockGroupID |        Col2         |
:--------------+---------------------:
|            1 | Novelty Items       |
:--------------+---------------------:
|            2 | Clothing            |
:--------------+---------------------:
|            3 | Mugs                |
:--------------+---------------------:
|            4 | T-Shirts            |
:--------------+---------------------:
|            5 | Airline Novelties   |
:--------------+---------------------:
|            6 | Computing Novelties |
:--------------+---------------------:
|            7 | USB Novelties       |
:--------------+---------------------:
|            8 | Furry Footwear      |
:--------------+---------------------:
|            9 | Toys                |
:--------------+---------------------:
|           10 | Packaging Materials |
'--------------'---------------------'`

This table has all the items and as you can see some items can be in multiple categories.

`.-----------------------.--------------.
| StockItemStockGroupID | StockGroupID |
:-----------------------+--------------:
|                     4 |            1 |
:-----------------------+--------------:
|                     1 |            2 |
:-----------------------+--------------:
|                     2 |            2 |
:-----------------------+--------------:
|                     3 |            3 |
:-----------------------+--------------:
|                     5 |            4 |
:-----------------------+--------------:
|                     6 |            7 |
:-----------------------+--------------:
|                     8 |            7 |
:-----------------------+--------------:
|                     7 |            8 |
:-----------------------+--------------:
|                     9 |            9 |
:-----------------------+--------------:
|                    10 |            2 |
'-----------------------'--------------'`

here is also another table that has all the names of the items so I can search based on keywords. But I don't think I need that here. So what I've tried to do is change the WHERE statement to a IN like this:

`WHERE SG.StockGroupID IN (SELECT StockGroupID FROM stockitemstockgroups)`
however it still won't hold multiple categories. This is the URL

http://localhost/kbs/zoek.php?producttitle=pizza&prodgroup=1

While I think it's supposed to be like this:

http://localhost/kbs/zoek.php?producttitle=pizza&prodgroup=1&prodgroup=2

Comment: Nice, localhost link.

Comment: localhost urls are only accessible to you. We - as remote people - can not access **local**host

Comment: Hello JoyMan ... welcome.  First off, your code is subject to SQL Injection attacks.  Please read up on filter_input() and what an SQL Injection attack is.

Next, consider whether your application would benefit from using a FullText Search Engine, such as Lucene, SphinxSearch, ElasticSearch, etc.  LIKE searches directly in the database can be made to work OK, but if you want *relevant* results you're gonna have some issues ... issues that the Lucene/Sphinx/Elastic teams have already addressed in their software.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736284/mysql-where-in)  hold the answer for you?

Comment: Also, in order to search *all* categories, it should be as simple as omitting the category test in the SQL.  But you might not want to do that if you have millions of rows to search ...

Comment: define "multiple categories"? IF it's *every* category, then you simply search the Products table. If it's a user choice of categories then use [this link from my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736284/mysql-where-in)

Comment: @Martin [Here is a screenshot of the website](https://i.imgur.com/LXOlqPL.png) So the USB novelties is highlighted which means now I'm in that category. I know when I search the term 'Pizza' it shows up in that category. However I know that that particular USB with the term 'Pizza' is in 2 other categories. That's what I mean with multiple categories. Cause at the moment when I click to a different category it just switches without remembering that I clicked on USB novelties and searches for a 'Pizza' product in a different category.  I tried the post you linked didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey as of now I'm aware of SQL injection this is just a little project I wanted to try out. I actually have wrote a little code that searches the database without selecting any category here it is: `(isset($_GET['producttitle']) && $_GET['producttitle'] != "") {
 $like = "%" . $_GET['producttitle'] . "%";
 $query = $readconn->prepare("SELECT S.StockItemID, S.StockItemName, S.Photo, S.UnitPrice, S.Photo FROM stockitems S WHERE StockItemName LIKE ?");
                $query->execute(array($like));`

Comment: @JoyMan so you want: `"find this product with id X in categories that are NOT current category"` and output th result as additional categories.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should transform the where part of your query to somethng like

```
WHERE SG.StockGroupID IN (" . $categories . ") ...
```

where $categories should be a string like '1,2,4' created
using a UI that allow the User to pick the categories he needs.

Comment: I tried this `WHERE SG.StockGroupID IN ('".$category."')` didn't do it for me.